# error while reading mails in camel

Tags: email, apache-camel, pop3

```
<camel:from uri="pop3://125.55.100.14?username=test@mydomain.com&amp;consumer.delay=30000&amp;mapMailMessage=false&amp;delete=true&amp;unseen=true&amp;password=test"/>
```

I am using this route to read mail from my mailbox

However i m getting following error,

```
*javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException*: The system was unable to log test@mydomain.com in.  Maildrop (file ) can not be located or opened.  Please contact your POP3 administrator.
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:208)[84:javax.mail:1.4.5]
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)[84:javax.mail:1.4.5]
    at org.apache.camel.component.mail.MailConsumer.ensureIsConnected(MailConsumer.java:376)[218:org.apache.camel.camel-mail:2.10.0.fuse-71-047]
    at org.apache.camel.component.mail.MailConsumer.poll(MailConsumer.java:82)[218:org.apache.camel.camel-mail:2.10.0.fuse-71-047]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:142)[129:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.0.fuse-71-047]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:92)[129:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.0.fuse-71-047]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)[:1.7.0_21]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:351)[:1.7.0_21]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:178)[:1.7.0_21]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)[:1.7.0_21]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)[:1.7.0_21]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)[:1.7.0_21]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)[:1.7.0_21]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)[:1.7.0_21]
```

please help me

Answer (score 0):

It's strange that it says `Maildrop (file )` without naming the file. It should be `Maildrop (file mail\xxxx)` or something similar. So, my first guess is that this error hasn't to do anything with the Camel configuration.

Comment: i have tested code on local server i have setup(hmailserver) code was working file. I did telnet to my account ,i was able to do list